# Routing between LazyLoading routes not working

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngrx

I'm building an Angular project with NGRX and Lazy Loading. But when I need to navigate from one module to other from the component ts file, the navigation is not working. It enters an infinite loop.

This is my app-routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'transaction',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/transaction/transaction.module').then(m => m.TransactionModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
  }
]
```

And the app-routing:

```
{
    path: 'transaction',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/transaction/transaction.module').then(m => m.TransactionModule)
  }
```

(If I do a deep link to the transaction confirmation page it works as expected)

The issue is when a user (from a user component, create a transaction and I want to redirect the url to a transaction component.

This is the component where the user create a transaction

```
import { itemSelector, actionSelector } from '../../store/user.selectors';
import { itemSelector as transactionSelector, actionSelector as transactionActionSelector } from '../../../transaction/store/transaction.selectors';
....
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  item$!: Observable<UserModel | null>;
  item!: UserModel;
  transaction$!: Observable<TransactionModel | null>;
  lastActionResponse!: UserActionEnum | null;
  transactionLastActionResponse!: TransactionActionEnum | null;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.transaction$ = this.transactionStore.pipe(select(transactionSelector));
    this.item$ = this.store.pipe(select(itemSelector));

    this.transactionStore.pipe(select(transactionActionSelector)).subscribe((action: TransactionActionEnum | null) => {
      this.transactionLastActionResponse = action;
    });


    this.store.pipe(select(actionSelector)).subscribe((action: UserActionEnum | null) => {
      this.lastActionResponse = action;
    });

    this.transaction$.subscribe((transaction: TransactionModel | null) => {
      if (transaction && this.transactionLastActionResponse === TransactionActionEnum.OWNTRADE) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl(`/transaction/confirmation`);
      }
    });

    this.item$.subscribe((item: UserModel | null) => {
      if (item && this.lastActionResponse == UserActionEnum.FINDONE) {
        this.item = item;
    }
});
}

submit() {
    this.transactionStore.dispatch(ownTradeAction({ res: item }));
}
```

The reducer (this is executed after the effect call the service to create the transaction in the backend):

```
on(ownTradeSuccessAction, (state, {res}) => ({ ...state, item: res, lastSuccessfulAction: TransactionActionEnum.OWNTRADE})),
```

And the transaction route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'confirmation',
    component: TransactionConfirmationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {
      role: ['admin', 'client']
    }
  },{
    path: ':id',
    component: TransactionDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {
      role: ['admin', 'client']
    }
  }
]
```

So when a transaction is created, the app enters in a loop between `this.transaction$.subscribe` and `this.item$.subscribe` and although it goes to the `navidationByUrl` (I also tried `router.navigation`), the page is never redirected

If I change the URL for one corresponding to the user module, it works, but not when it is in another module.
Besides that, I have no idea why it keeps going to the item subscriber as there is no change there.

Comment: Where are you dispatching the action to update the store value? Also I see you are passing a transactionid, but in your router definition of the module, I don't see you have posted the router for the :id form. Something like 

const routes: Routes = [{path: ':id', component: TransactionComponent}]

Comment: @FernandoMorales thanks for you r reply. I added the routing and dispaching. Also I corrected the right url for the redirection, in some of my test I changed to one using the _id but that was just a test.